# Bonferroni application

Tags: bonferroni

My dataset compares the impact of 2 shoes at 3 speeds on a dependant variable. When it comes to post hoc pairwise testing I would look at

1. shoe1 vs shoe2 at every speed
2. speed 1 vs speed 2; speed 2 vs speed 3; speed 3 vs speed 1 for each shoe

Would i apply Bonferroni 2 times for the first set of 3 and 6 tests, or one time for all 9 tests?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay let me rephrase: the way i see it I have 2 sets of possible pairwise comparisons, those being Shoe vs Shoe at all 3 speeds (3 tests) and speed vs speed with both shoes (also 3 tests for each shoe or 6 tests for both shoes). Now i am not sure if i should adjust the alpha level. Should i correct the alpha level of the first set to 0.0167 (based on 0.05/3) and do that to all sets or do i look at all tests as one big set and adjust to 0.0056 (based on 0.05/9)?